# electron/electron-builder running out of memory

Tags: reactjs, node.js, webpack, electron, electron-builder

The title says it mostly, but to explain further: I am trying to run and build an electron application that runs a webpack react app and am encountering some problems with heap memory running out. This problem has recently come up and seems unrelated to any code changes we've made over the past few updates, and is currently blocking us from packaging our app and releasing it.

When running the application with `electron .`, the following logs are spit out, but no 'error' occurs:

```
24  Electron Framework                  0x000000010ace7840 _ZN2v88internal20SetupIsolateDelegate9SetupHeapEPNS0_4HeapE + 2396044
25  Electron Framework                  0x000000010ace3bc0 _ZN2v88internal20SetupIsolateDelegate9SetupHeapEPNS0_4HeapE + 2380556
26  Electron Framework                  0x000000010ac91b6c _ZN2v88internal20SetupIsolateDelegate9SetupHeapEPNS0_4HeapE + 2044600
27  Electron Framework                  0x000000010ac91900 _ZN2v88internal20SetupIsolateDelegate9SetupHeapEPNS0_4HeapE + 2043980
28  Electron Framework                  0x000000010a4d9840 ElectronInitializeICUandStartNode + 5735672
29  Electron Framework                  0x000000010a4d9cec ElectronInitializeICUandStartNode + 5736868
30  Electron Framework                  0x0000000109f6130c ElectronMain + 116
31  Electron                            0x00000001028371dc Electron + 12764
32  dyld                                0x00000001a637fe50 start + 2544
```

Although no error occurs, the React application does not render. The React app does run and build fine when run standalone.

I first encountered the issue when trying to run `electron-builder -mw` to build for release and similar logs appeared, although with the explicit error as follows:

```
<--- Last few GCs --->

[2820:0x150008000]    50798 ms: Scavenge 8109.9 (8212.4) -> 8109.6 (8223.2) MB, 6.9 / 0.0 ms  (average mu = 0.356, current mu = 0.249) allocation failure 
[2820:0x150008000]    50823 ms: Scavenge 8116.6 (8223.2) -> 8117.4 (8224.2) MB, 12.0 / 0.0 ms  (average mu = 0.356, current mu = 0.249) allocation failure 
[2820:0x150008000]    52552 ms: Scavenge 8117.4 (8224.2) -> 8116.6 (8247.2) MB, 1728.2 / 0.0 ms  (average mu = 0.356, current mu = 0.249) allocation failure 


<--- JS stacktrace --->

FATAL ERROR: Reached heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory
 1: 0x10481352c node::Abort() [/Users/jacobmacweb/.nvm/versions/node/v16.20.0/bin/node]
 2: 0x10481371c node::ModifyCodeGenerationFromStrings(v8::Local<v8::Context>, v8::Local<v8::Value>, bool) [/Users/jacobmacweb/.nvm/versions/node/v16.20.0/bin/node]
```

I've ran with `NODE_OPTIONS='--max-old-space-size=8192'` and `NODE_OPTIONS='--max-old-space-size=16384'` to no avail, with the same memory limits being reached as if it were ignoring my `NODE_OPTIONS`. I'd expect to run this command and have the built packages, as it has done the hundred or so times I've run this command before.

For more context:

- Apple Macbook M2 Pro
- Node.js 16.20 (with nvm)
- Electron ^11.5.0
- Electron-builder ^22.11.7

If there's any other info needed please let me know/ask me! I'll be actively looking out for responses.

Comment: Seems like, there is an infinite loop inside your codebase. Actually, hard to get to know what might be the problem. First, I'd recommend you review recent changes since the app stopped working.

Comment: If your react app can be loaded on the browser, please try to build react files first host a local server, and check if everything works fine in the browser. This means, your react (renderer) part is OK. And error is coming from the main process or electron-builder.

Answer (score 0):

I faced this issue when my Electron build size was over 500mb. I would recommend compressing/reducing your assets or loading them externally away from the build.

Once I reduced my assets by about 40% the build ran successfully again